# How to get answer from messagebox

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I copy

```
if ((MessageBox::Show(
     "Are you sure that you would like to close the form?", 
     "Form Closing", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, 
     MessageBoxIcon::Question) == DialogResult::No))
  {
     // cancel the closure of the form.
     Application::Exit();
  }
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx). Where I compiling this i have

> 1>------ Build started: Project: test2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  test2.cpp
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(103): error C2039: 'No' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::DialogResult'
>   1>          c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(16) : see declaration of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::DialogResult'
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(103): error C2065: 'No' : undeclared identifier
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

What's wrong? How fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m stumped but the MSDN article for [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) mentions in the C++ example that the type name should be prefixed with `::` to make it non-nested. Maybe try this:

```
if (MessageBox::Show(
     "Are you sure that you would like to close the form?", 
     "Form Closing", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, 
     MessageBoxIcon::Question) == ::DialogResult::No)
```

(I also removed the redundant parentheses …)

If it doesn’t help, try specifying the full namespace, i.e. `::System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::No` to see if that at least works.

Comment: Work with ::System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::No. Thanks. (I can't accept this answer now)